# Animating content from a div that is displayed inside another div

Tags: javascript, jquery

Really new to jquery, so any help appreciated it.

Trying to solve a design challenge. I needed to display the content from a `div` inside another `div`, on hover of a third element. 
Found some code that helped me put it together, but I wonder if there is a way to animate (slidedown, fadein, etc.) the content when is displayed.

Any idea how can I apply animation to the .html function when it displays the content?

```
var divContent = $("#explore-agility-content").html('');
$( ".industry" ).hover(
    function() {
        $("#explore-agility-content").html( $( this).find("#shortdesc").html() );
    }, 
    function() {
        $("#explore-agility-content").html( divContent );
    }
);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rnwebdesigner/3wyrwd92/71/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are fadeIn fadeOut effects on hover and mouseout

check this fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/parthjasani/3wyrwd92/72/

```
var divContent = $("#explore-agility-content").html('');
$(".industry").hover(

    function () {
        $("#explore-agility-content").html($(this).find("#shortdesc").html());
        $("#explore-agility-content .wb").hide().fadeIn()
    },

    function () {
        $("#explore-agility-content .wb").fadeOut(function () {
            $("#explore-agility-content").html(divContent);
        })
    }

);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add and remove css classes which can contain several properties to be transitioned on mouse enter and leave..

See snippet below **(solution 1)**

```js
$('.image').mouseenter(function(){
        $(".text").addClass("animate")
});
$('.image').mouseleave(function(){
            $(".text").removeClass("animate")
});
```

```css
.image {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    display: block;
    background-color: red;
    
}
.text {
    background-color: white;
    padding:40px;
       transition:all 0.5s;
}

.left {
        display:block;
        height:400px;
        width: 400px;
        background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGlzr.png') no-repeat 0 0 scroll;
    background-color:#0C0C0C;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
        }
 .animate{
   
   opacity:1 !important;
   padding-top:50px;

 }
 .noanimate{
   opacity:0;
   padding-top:-50px
   
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="image"></div>
<div class="left">
          <div class="text noanimate">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed tincidunt consequat tristique. Curabitur vestibulum semper nulla id ornare.
          </div>

</div>
```

**Solution 2 - using hover function instead of mounseenter and leave**

```js
$('.image').hover(function(){
        $(".text").toggleClass("animate")
});
```

```css
.image {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    display: block;
    background-color: red;
    
}
.text {
    background-color: white;
    padding:40px;
       transition:all 0.5s;
}

.left {
        display:block;
        height:400px;
        width: 400px;
        background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGlzr.png') no-repeat 0 0 scroll;
    background-color:#0C0C0C;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
        }
 .animate{
   
   opacity:1 !important;
   padding-top:50px;

 }
 .noanimate{
   opacity:0;
   padding-top:-50px
   
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="image"></div>
<div class="left">
          <div class="text noanimate">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed tincidunt consequat tristique. Curabitur vestibulum semper nulla id ornare.
          </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I initially posted the wrong link to the jsfiddle, so the correct one is https://jsfiddle.net/rnwebdesigner/3wyrwd92/71/ But your idea is great too.